# Environment variabes - when and why

Tags: batch-file

Given [Raymond Chen's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/jj853254(v=msdn.10)) and conventional wisdom I'm curious about some observations:

First, if I'm quick and run `set` in a batch window on start-up (up-to-date Windows 10 Home) then I get a list of the environment variables I expect to be established.

But leave it a while and some other variables are created on further `cmd` instances `FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING` and `FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING` - apparently created by the Edge browser.

I have an initialisation batch executed by a link from the startup directory. This batch backs up some important directories and performs some other tasks. One of those tasks is to remove the icons that *DROPBOX* annoyingly imposes over icons `zapiconoverlays`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Get rid of dropbox-generated icon overlays
:: Provide a parameter to NOT restart explorer

SET "spaces=                                    "
(
ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
ECHO/
FOR /L %%I IN (0,1,10) DO (
 FOR /L %%L IN (101,1,110) DO (
  SET /a iter=%%L
  FOR %%K IN (WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
              Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
             ) DO (
   ECHO [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\%%K\!spaces:~0,%%I!DropboxExt!iter:~-2!]
  )
 )
)
)>u:\zapiconoverlays.REG

regedit /s u:\zapiconoverlays.REG
del u:\zapiconoverlays.REG

SET "spaces=%~1"
SET "iter="
IF NOT DEFINED spaces CALL restartexplorer
GOTO :eof
```

Which I normally run without a parameter, so `restartexplorer` is executed:

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
DEL %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db /a 2>nul
START explorer.exe
```

The curious thing is that variables that have been established in the local environment when `restartexplorer` is executed are then propagated to further `cmd` instances. For instance, I process the current date/time into various environment variables. If I run `zapiconoverlays` first thing in the initialisation batch (after a `setlocal`) then all runs as I expect, but if I put the `zapiconoverlays` call after having established the datetime variables, then the datetime variables are available in further `cmd` instances.

I'm looking for confirmation of my observations and possibly a rule that can be applied.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150915-00/?p=91591?

Comment: When a program is started it inherits it's starting programs current environment.